# SQL: Hierarchical Data path of best fit

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

I found a really great article that allows me to create SQL Hierarchical Data, [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). However, this is only the first part of the challenge I wanted to solve. I want to search for a path of best fit in this data using only one SQL statement or transaction.

From the link we have this tree: data tree below with the following SQL table representation.

[image: data tree]

```
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
| category_id | name                 | lft | rgt |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
|           1 | ELECTRONICS          |   1 |  20 |
|           2 | TELEVISIONS          |   2 |   9 |
|           3 | TUBE                 |   3 |   4 |
|           4 | LCD                  |   5 |   6 |
|           5 | PLASMA               |   7 |   8 |
|           6 | PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |  10 |  19 |
|           7 | MP3 PLAYERS          |  11 |  14 |
|           8 | FLASH                |  12 |  13 |
|           9 | CD PLAYERS           |  15 |  16 |
|          10 | 2 WAY RADIOS         |  17 |  18 |
+-------------+----------------------+-----+-----+
```

Lets say I have input's: (ELECTRONICS, PORTABLE ELECTRONICS, MP3 PLAYERS, FLASH) and another example (ELECTRONICS, LCD).

The definition of "**the path of best fit**" is the longest path that includes all the nodes I specify that make a unbroken path from the root node.

For my first input the path of best fir is:

```
+----------------------+
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| ELECTRONICS          |
| PORTABLE ELECTRONICS |
| MP3 PLAYERS          |
| FLASH                |
+----------------------+
```

For the second input:

```
+----------------------+
| name                 |
+----------------------+
| ELECTRONICS          |
+----------------------+
```

In the second example we can see that there is no unbroken path to from the root ELECTRONICS to LCD.

I would like to know how can I make a SQL query or transaction that would allow me to do this. I am allow to modify the table or add new tables that would make this easier. **How do I make a query/transaction for the path of best fit?**

Comment: Have you read Joe Celko's books,  it;s the better approach to the wherabouts of binary trees and hierarchical data in relational databases.  There are 4 methods to work with.  Your image corresponds to the second method.

Comment: No, I haven't I'll give it a read.